# iOS8: Implementing a iAd Singleton

Tags: ios, ios8, singleton, iad

I'm struggling with this. I've added the subview correctly and get no errors, however no iAd is ever shown, even though the method bannerViewDidLoadAd definitely gets called. Any advice what I'm doing wrong?

```
#import "Advertisments.h"

@implementation Advertisments

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static Advertisments *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(screenBounds.size.width / 2.0, screenBounds.size.height + 25.0);

        _bannerView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(screenBounds.size.width / 2.0, screenBounds.size.height - 25.0);
                     }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(screenBounds.size.width / 2.0, screenBounds.size.height + 25.0);
                     }];
}
```

And in my view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
//Add ads
    [self.view addSubview:[[Advertisments sharedManager] bannerView]];
```

Comment: what is your view hierarchy? and when do you add the ads view? it is possible your ads view is being obscured by other views

Comment: I add this view in the viewDidLoad method and the rest of the views I created in Interface Builder. I thought as well it might be obscured, but then I lifted it on top of all other views and it still wasn't visible

Comment: Did you take a look at iAD samples from Apple? specifically iAd suite